# Both vertical and horizontal data in WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm struggling at making a datagrid that looks like this :

`|Column 1 | Column 2|
 |  data1  | data2   |
 |Column 3 | data3   |`

I've no problem doing this using a simple grid and defining rows + columns but I can't do it using a datagrid because `<DataGrid.Rows>` is not available. The only few posts I found about it suggested to make a grid but if it's possible to do that using a DataGrid, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` maps a column to a property of the underlying type `T` in its `IEnumerable<T>` `ItemsSource`, and generates a row per instance of `T`. This is how it works basically.

If you want to be able to add columns or/and rows in some other way, you should use a different approach. The built-in `DataGrid` control won't work as expected anyway.

Comment: Mmh I see so the only way is basically to build my own grid and then create a user control to make the bindings ?

Comment: Well, something like that. You can put whatever you want in a DataGrid *cell* by using a DataGridTemplateColumn but you can't really add rows that are not part of the ItemsSource.